# Appending a dataframe Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, np

Can't seem to do this at all.

So I have

```
df.Name.unique()
```

Which spits out a list of names.

```
['BKH' 'EDE']
```

And I have

```
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name'])
```

And I want to append new to essentially have a list of names to put into new (column = 'Name)

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

I thought that since df.Name.unique() gives me a list I could use it to append to another dataframe that only has one column.

Thanks in advance guys I hope you're having a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add parameter `data` to [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, because output of [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) is `numpy array`:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['BKH','BKH','EDE']})
print (df)
  Name
0  BKH
1  BKH
2  EDE

print (df.Name.unique())
['BKH' 'EDE']

new = pd.DataFrame(data=df.Name.unique(), columns=['Name'])
print (new)
  Name
0  BKH
1  EDE
```

Answer (score 0):

actually guys its all good I have figure it out

```
values = df.Name.unique()

new['Name'] = values
print(new)
```

spits out

```
  Name
0  BKH
1  EDE
```